# Finding the difference between columns for lots of columns in dataframe

Tags: r

I was looking at the JHU dataset for COVID-19 cases in the US and world. Basically, This dataset has county and state as row elements and successive dates as columns. The value in the date-labeled columns is cumulative COVID-19 cases in the county.

```
# A tibble: 3,342 x 965
      UID iso2  iso3  code3  FIPS Admin2  Province_State Country_Region   Lat
     <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>          <chr>          <dbl>
1 84001001 US    USA     840  1001 Autauga Alabama        US              32.5
2 84001003 US    USA     840  1003 Baldwin Alabama        US              30.7
[stuff deleted]
# ... with 956 more variables: Long_ <dbl>, Combined_Key <chr>,
#   `1/22/20` <dbl>, `1/23/20` <dbl>, `1/24/20` <dbl>, `1/25/20` <dbl>,
[stuff deleted]
#   `2/11/20` <dbl>, `2/12/20` <dbl>, `2/13/20` <dbl>, `2/14/20` <dbl>, ...
```

To find the daily number of new cases, I was looking at various methods, ranging from base-R to vanilla tidyverse to functional solutions. The base-R solution was eventually the fastest by an order of magnitude (or 2-3). Are there any other options for a fast difference of columns?

The expected end-result should be

```
# A tibble: 3,178,728 x 5
    FIPS name    value cases date
   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <date>
 1  1001 1/22/20     0    NA 2020-01-22
 2  1001 1/23/20     0     0 2020-01-23
 3  1001 1/24/20     0     0 2020-01-24
```

### 1: Tidyverse style pivot_longer, group_by() and mutate()

```
us_cases3 <-
    us_cases_raw %>%
    select(-c(1:4, 6:11)) %>%
    pivot_longer(!FIPS) %>%
    group_by(FIPS) %>%
    mutate(date = mdy(name),
            cases = value - lag(value))  %>%
    ungroup()
# Time difference of 24.52673 secs

# Without group_by(): Time difference of 1.519198 secs (this obviously give a wrong answer
# but shows where most of the time is spent)
```

### method 2: base-R

```
us_cases2 <- us_cases_raw[-c(1:4, 6:11)]
ncol <- ncol(us_cases2)
us_cases3 <- cbind(us_cases2[1], 
                   us_cases2[3:(ncol)] - us_cases2[2:(ncol-1)]) %>% 
             pivot_longer(!FIPS) %>% mutate(date = mdy(name))
# Time difference of 1.550864 secs
```

### method 3: convoluted purrr::map_* or future::future_map_* functions

```
us_cases4 <-
    us_cases_raw %>%
    select(-c(1:4, 6:11)) %>%
    pivot_longer(!FIPS)

    us_cases3 <- map_dfr(unique(us_cases4$FIPS), ~ subset(us_cases4, FIPS == .x) %>% mutate(cases = value - lag(value))) %>%
    mutate(date = mdy(name))
# Time difference of 3.801137 mins

# and multiprocessing included through library(future) / plan(multisession
us_cases4 <-
    us_cases_raw %>%
    select(-c(1:4, 6:11)) %>%
    pivot_longer(!FIPS)

    us_cases3 <- future_map_dfr(unique(us_cases4$FIPS), ~ subset(us_cases4, FIPS == .x) %>% mutate(cases = value - lag(value))) %>%
    mutate(date = mdy(name))
# Time difference of 1.580935 mins
```

Comment: You may try with `melt` from `data.table`, should be faster than pivot_longer i.e. `library(data.table);melt(setDT(us_cases_raw)[, -c(1:4, 6:11), with = FALSE], id.var = "FIPS")[, date := mdy(variable)] [, cases := value - shift(value) , .(FIPS)][]`

Comment: The biggest time sink for method for method 1 (which includes a `pivot_longer()`) is the `group_by()`. Not using `group_by()` makes the method run as fast as the best.